# iplots with time series data

Tags: r, time-series, iplots

I have a two columns. One date and the second data. I need to create a time series charts with iplots. Cannot find any docs with time series? Can anybody help with some starter pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the best is to make sure you have the time variable in `POSIXct` format, so use `as.POSIXct` if in doubt. Then you can use `iplot(ts, y)`.

In iPlots eXtreme (Acinonyx) you can press `L` to add lines connecting data points. If you have multiple time series, you can use `its(ts, y, group)` for interactive time series.

In the old iPlots you can use `ilines(ts, y)` to connect the points instead.

All of the above assumes that the data is ordered by `ts` (which is typically true).

Please consider using [stats-rosuda-devel](http://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) mailing list of iPlots questions.